# AngularJS pass function to ng-repeat from object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can i solve this problem, or it's a bad way with `ng-repeat`?

The markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in Ctrl.cars">
    <span>{{::car.color}}</span>
    <span>{{::car.type}}</span>
    <input ng-change="{{::car.function}}"/>
</div>
```

The js:

```
scope.cars = [
    {color: 'red', type: 'Ferrari', function:''},
    {color: 'green', type: 'Subaru', function: scope.doSomething},
];
```

I would like to run `doSomething()` on input change. You know a solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed regarding your snippet is that you are using a reserved keyword `function` as the key of a JS object. You are free to do so IF you let JS know it's a string: `{ "function": "someotherval" }`

To call a function from the view, you could do this:

```html
<input ng-change="car['function']()"/>
```

In case Angular cannot cope with this syntax, I'd suggest going with something like `changeCallback` as the key for the value. This worked for me:

```html
<input ng-change="car.changeCallback()"/>
```

```json
{color: 'red', type: 'Ferrari', changeCallback: scope.doSomethingAmazing }
```

The function itself need to be defined:

```javascript
scope.doSomethingAmazing = function() { /* */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `function`, since it's a JS keyword. Let's say you rename the field to `functionToCall`...

Second, you must not use interpolation, and you must **call** the function:

```
<input ng-change="car.functionToCall()"/>
```

If you want nothing to happen for some cars, then don't initialize the function to call with a string, initialize it with a function that does nothing:

```
{color: 'red', type: 'Ferrari', functionToCall: angular.noop}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was useful, i am new in Angularjs, i didn't hear about `angular.noop`. Of course `function` is just example. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're close yes... that's how it works you just do:

```
<input ng-model="car.myModel" ng-change="car.myFunction(car.myModel)"/>
```